# Prove interval is open by considering function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I can't seem to understand the last step in this proof.  How did they get the equivalence with $f^{-1}(-\infty,r)$?  For reference, this proof is for the book "Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak

Thanks in advance

> [image]

Comment: The inequality $|\ \|x-a\| - \|b - a\|\ | \leq \|x - a\| - \|b - a\|$ looks wrong to me (this is in effect claiming that the absolute value of a number is less than or equal to the number), but fortunately it's not needed, since $|\ \|x-a\| - \|b - a\|\ | \leq \|x - b\|$ by the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuos function, preimage of open sets is open.

Here $(-\infty, r)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah.  That explains it.  Is it also true that the preimage of closed sets is closed?

Comment: Yes, that is true for continuous function.